# ICertRequest2::Submit CSR data Compatability ASCII to BSTR

Tags: cryptography, ascii, bstr, csr, base-conversion

I have my certrequest as a PEM base64 data. See data below.

1) My understanding is that this is an ASCII data type and not in
UNICODE format. Please clarify.

-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIBTjCBuAIBADARMQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZ3dTAwMzEwgZ0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD
gYsAMIGHAoGBAKP48eljetv3fVicT6g6hKjmLpsySJaZ/NnepEJEqtQQNbwsluhW
yWxhHWzPoNPV9uqjZBW7EnqYjxyPp1A0vOK35uxmmcNrgmuSjO1WBkD0YVZwzh2u
OovRCOwJKklQtJnQWoM+yT8CyBVk7raVJOrLDMC8FR5AMknVCIlt7HppAgEDoAAw
DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEAAK5G10e39GxiNiPXdrOAwtuIiLd1UTWn3VYY7nYY
74LhydUBjo0Xi6HBTTNVlPNoRB9GOe5P1Qgq0EJ6gLIriFY+Gxdl2Y4lSo7FmpxB
+87bRCLpC3mxQltNm97ZysmS4I4diYhPDSS/2acKeH2cBgAtQVG9KsuZ41qxUQ10
EY8=
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

2) If the above data is in ASCII, how can i convert it to BSTR, as
ICertRequest2::Submit requires the data to be unicode string.

3) Can i convert the ASCII data directly to BSTR

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. Use [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(VS.85).aspx) before calling `SysAllocString` (or `SysAllocStringLen`)
2. Use [`_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [`CComBSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f%28VS.80%29.aspx) which are C++ wrappers for BSTRs.

Comment: Hello Rasmus, Thanks; I am using your option 1. But i am not sure what option i should use for   
__in   UINT CodePage,
__in   DWORD dwFlags,
I am using CP_ACP (default) and using zero for the flags. For my case, do you think these options are ok? MS warns about CP_ACP as a varying one from PC to PC. If i want to configure the PC to keep it as constant, iS there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter at all which flags you use, since your data is pure ASCII (ie. no characters with values >127). If you are worried about the warnings, just use CP_UTF8. If you want to know more about codepages there is a short article here: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/08/389527.aspx

Answer (score 0):

US-ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. The encoded form of any ASCII character is the UTF-8 encoding, so no conversion is needed.

Simply pass the string as-is, setting the `CR_IN_BASE64HEADER` flag.

Comment: Hello Erickson - Thank you for your answer.I donot know whether i am confused here for no reasons. I am reading my CSR from disk. I am reading the CSR as two buffer types
char*  mDataBuffer1;
wchar_t* mDataBuffer;
I am getting the lengths for the first char* as 548 and wchar_t* as 274; The second case's length is calculated below
RequestBuff = SysAllocString(mDataBuffer);->548 as returned by CreateFile fn
long len = SysStringLen(RequestBuff);->274
Which of my declaration should i need to follow?
I am sure that the secons one is wrong. Should i have to declare as char* and proceed
Thank you
Raj

Comment: Hi Raj. I'm not sure I follow your question exactly, but I believe you should pass a char* with length of 548.

Comment: Hello Erickson - I am trying the followin
1. Read the CSR from disk which is char* DataBuffer
2. bstrRequest = SysAllocString(DataBuffer);
   If i keep the CSR as char* then SysAllocString throws an error as it is expecting only wchar_t* instead of char*; So this prompted me to change the char* to wchar_t*
3. hr = pCertRequest->Submit(CR_IN_BASE64HEADER|CR_IN_PKCS10,
                    bstrRequest,
                    bstrAttribute,
                    bstrCA,
                    &vDispositionCode);

So thats the reason why i wanted to change my string type? I am making any sense?

Thanks
Raj